# Find the number of occurrences of key in the database

Tags: mongodb

Hi I am new to MongoDB and am trying to learn it by running queries in an existing database with 10000+ documents.

This consist of user documents, with the key "usertype" as either "FACULTY" OR "STUDENT".

While trying to find the count of documents with the respective usertypes,I get the following result

> db.user.find( { "usertype": "FACULTY"}).count()
>   391
>
> db.user.find( { "usertype": "STUDENT"}).count()
>   8846

However, while trying to find the total count of documents I get

> db.user.find().count()
>   9289

How can I find out the missing 52 documents. I am sure that all documents have the key value "usertype"

I have tried searching for documents with usertype NULL. But the count is 0.

---

I tried the following to check if there are unknown usretypes

> db.user.distinct("usertype") [ "ADMIN", "HOD", "FACULTY", "STUDENT", "alternate" ] 
>   db.user.find({"usertype" : "HOD").count() ... ... >
>   db.user.find({"usertype":"ADMIN"}).count() 6 
>   db.user.find({"usertype":"alternate"}).count() 17 
>   db.user.find({"usertype":"HOD"}).count() 28 
>   db.user.find({"usertype":"FACULTY"}).count() 391 
>   db.user.find({"usertype":"STUDENT"}).count() 8846 
>   8846+391+28+17+6 9288 
>   db.user.find().count() 9289.

Again 1 document seems to be missing.and there are no documents with usertype = "null" –

Comment: It can be other types aswell? Try to search for all ordered by usertype excluding faculty and student. Also try your query with usertype = "" (empty string)

Answer (score 0):

you could try the condition not equal $ne

```
db.user.find( { usertype: { $ne: "FACULTY", $ne: "STUDENT" } } )
```

Comment: I tried the following 2 check 4 unknown usretypes > db.user.distinct("usertype")
[ "ADMIN", "HOD", "FACULTY", "STUDENT", "alternate" ]
> db.user.find({"usertype" : "HOD").count()
...
...
>
> db.user.find({"usertype":"ADMIN"}).count()
6
> db.user.find({"usertype":"alternate"}).count()
17
> db.user.find({"usertype":"HOD"}).count()
28
> db.user.find({"usertype":"FACULTY"}).count()
391
> db.user.find({"usertype":"STUDENT"}).count()
8846
> 8846+391+28+17+6
9288
> db.user.find().count()
9289. Again 1 document seems to be missing.and there are no documents with usertype = "null"

Answer (score 0):

You could first of all check the distinct values of the usertype field across a single collection and return the results in an array. Use the **[`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)** method for this:

```
db.users.distinct("usertype")
```

With the array returned, you can use it to construct an aggregation pipeline that can give you the individual counts for each field value:

```
var usertypes = db.users.distinct("usertype"),
    groupOperator = { "$group": { "_id": null } };

usertypes.forEach(function (type){ 
    groupOperator["$group"][type.toLowerCase()] = { 
       "$sum": { 
           "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$usertype",  type ] }, 1, 0] 
       }
   }
});

db.users.aggregate([groupOperator]);
```

---

You can also try a couple of other queries to detemermine the other 52 docs:

```
var usertypes = ["FACULTY", "STUDENT"];
db.users.find({ "usertype": { "$nin": usertypes, "$exists": true } });
```

or the other query where you look for documents that do not have the usertype field:

```
db.users.find({ "usertype": { "$exists": false } })
```